# PHP foreach isn't inserting

Tags: php, mysql, xml, foreach, insert

I've been stuck on this for a while now and all the searches I did for this subject don't bring me the solution. This code inserts the value of the first product of the XML into MySQL table.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("URL") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->programs->products->product as $product);
foreach ($xml->programs->products->product->product_info->price as $price);

$insert = 'INSERT INTO BBB (price) VALUES (?)';
$insertStmt = $dbconnection->prepare($insert);
foreach ($product as $row) {
    $insertStmt->bind_param('s', $price);
}

$insertStmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";
```

After this I got the feedback that foreach doesn't work this way with prepared PHP statements. Thereafter I created this code:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("URL") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$insert = 'INSERT INTO BBB (price) VALUES (?)';
$insertStmt = $dbconnection->prepare($insert);
foreach ($tags as $key=>$val) {
    if ($key == "product") {
        $dcprice = $key->product_info->price;
        $productranges = $val;
        for ($i=0; $i < count($productranges); $i+=2) {
            $offset = $productranges[$i] + 1;
            $len = $productranges[$i + 1] - $offset;
            $price[] = $dcprice(array_slice($values, $offset, $len));
        }
    } 
    $insertStmt->bind_param('s', $price);
    $insertStmt->execute();
}
echo "New records created successfully";
```

The code echoes that new records are created, but when I check the table in phpMyAdmin nothing appears.

Examples of links I've been checking are: [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work), [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), [xml_parse_into_struct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php). But I can't find the right piece of information, would be great if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Its normal that it tells you that new records are created. At the end of your code you simply echo that phrase, without any `if` clause that checks if they were really inserted.

Comment: if $key != 'product' then it binds an undefined param ($price) and executes anyway

Comment: oh and the $price array is getting bigger in each iteration. you should reset $price for each tag

Comment: I had never thought of using an empty `foreach()` to fetch the last item in an array or iterable object. However, I don't think that was your intention...

Answer (score 0):

The following is not tested but I think it should give an idea. Create the `prepared statement` and bind a variable to the statement, then execute in a loop once you have declared the variable.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("URL") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$sql = 'INSERT INTO BBB (price) VALUES (?)';
$stmt = $dbconnection->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bind_param( 's', $price );


foreach ($tags as $key=>$val) {
    if ($key == "product") {
        $dcprice = $key->product_info->price;
        $productranges = $val;

        for($i=0; $i < count($productranges); $i+=2) {
            $offset = $productranges[$i] + 1;
            $len = $productranges[$i + 1] - $offset;

            $price = $dcprice(array_slice($values, $offset, $len));
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }   
}
echo "New records created successfully";
```

Basic example of inserting multiple records.

```
$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'experiments';

$db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


$sql='insert into `temp` (`val`) values (?)';
$stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bind_param( 's', $i );
    for( $i=0; $i < 100; $i++ )$stmt->execute();

    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

---

Using the actual data from the xml file ( but not using `simpleXML` )

```
$url='https://daisycon.io/datafeed/?filter_id=17940&settings_id=2510&demo';
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( $url );

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );



$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('product_info');
if( !empty( $col ) ){

    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'experiments';

    $db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    $sql='insert into `temp` (`brand`,`title`,`price`) values (?,?,?);';
    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){

        $stmt->bind_param( 'sss', $brand, $title, $price );

        foreach( $col as $i => $product ){
            $brand = $xp->query( 'brand', $product )->item( 0 )->nodeValue;
            $price = floatval( $xp->query( 'price', $product )->item( 0 )->nodeValue );
            $title = $xp->query( 'title', $product )->item( 0 )->nodeValue;

            $stmt->execute();
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    $db=null;
}
```

This runs through the xml and inserts the records as one would expect - I hope that this helps.

---

Example of reading the XML and displaying results - NO database, just to show how to read records!

```
$url='https://daisycon.io/datafeed/?filter_id=17940&settings_id=2510&demo';
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( $url );

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('product_info');
if( !empty( $col ) ){
    foreach( $col as $i => $product ){
        $data=array(
            'brand' =>  $xp->query( 'brand', $product )->item( 0 )->nodeValue,
            'title' =>  $xp->query( 'title', $product )->item( 0 )->nodeValue,
            'price' =>  floatval( $xp->query( 'price', $product )->item( 0 )->nodeValue )
        );
        echo '<ul><li>',implode('</li><li>',$data),'</li></ul>';
    }
}
```

This then outputs:

```
<ul>
   <li>Dr. Fix</li>
   <li>Dr. Fix Organic Droge Voeten Balsem 75 ml</li>
   <li>11.95</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Lamberts</li>
   <li>Lamberts Selenium ACE 100 TAB</li>
   <li>19.1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Annemarie Borlind</li>
   <li>Annemarie Borlind Lipcontourstift Red 1.05 G</li>
   <li>13.25</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Wapiti</li>
   <li>Wapiti Darmfunctie 20 dragees</li>
   <li>3.95</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Davitamon</li>
   <li>Davitamon Compleet Mama 60 capsules</li>
   <li>11.95</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Vitaminhealth</li>
   <li>Vitaminhealth Multi Vitaminen  30 tabletten</li>
   <li>9.95</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Vitaminhealth</li>
   <li>Vitaminhealth Multi Vitaminen  120 tabletten</li>
   <li>32.5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Vitaminhealth</li>
   <li>Vitaminhealth Multi Vitaminen  240 tabletten</li>
   <li>58.95</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Vitaminhealth</li>
   <li>Vitaminhealth Botformule 60 tabletten</li>
   <li>12.95</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Vitaminhealth</li>
   <li>Vitaminhealth Betacaroteen 60 softgels</li>
   <li>16.95</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Brita</li>
   <li>Brita Optimax Cool Wit Waterfilterkan 1 exemplaar</li>
   <li>49.95</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Essential Organics</li>
   <li>Essential Organics Cal Mag &amp; Zink  90 tabletten</li>
   <li>11.5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Vitotaal</li>
   <li>Vitotaal Canadese Geelwortel 45 vegicaps</li>
   <li>9.95</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Annemarie Borlind</li>
   <li>Annemarie Borlind Combination Skin Dagfluid  75 ml</li>
   <li>27.95</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Vitotaal</li>
   <li>Vitotaal Cranberry + C 45 vegicaps</li>
   <li>9.95</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Vital Cell Life</li>
   <li>Vital Cell Life Vitamine B6/B12 foliumzuur 60 cap</li>
   <li>12</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Brita</li>
   <li>Brita Marella XL Wit Waterfilterkan (3,5 liter) 1 exemplaar</li>
   <li>21.5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Plantina</li>
   <li>Plantina Astaxanthin-eco 60 capsules</li>
   <li>33.1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Terrasana</li>
   <li>Terrasana Umeboshi 150 G</li>
   <li>7.49</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>Solgar Vitamins</li>
   <li>Solgar Vitamins Digestive Enzymes 250 tabletten</li>
   <li>39.9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi RamRaider, thank you for the reply. I've tried the PHP by copying your code, changing the URL and then executing, but again it didn't insert any data. I really don't get what is going wrong. This is the link to the example XML for the data: [link](https://daisycon.io/datafeed/?filter_id=17940&settings_id=2510&demo)

Comment: Hi RamRaider, thanks again. The new code inserts data for one product, but doesn't go through the whole XML. Also with my previous code this happened. It inserted data for only one product. Does this have something to do with the fact that a product has an update_info and product_info section?

Comment: I've been trying your code @RamRaider, but it continuous to keep in inserting only one product. I don't get why it isn't inserting all the XML products... I asked my webhosting also if there are any restricties on the database, that it's only possible to insert one row for example. Do you think this could have anything to do with it?

Comment: Is it maybe possible that the $col is on the 'product_info' while each <product> exist out of two elements: <product_info> and <update_info>? So the loop keeps only going through this one.